# After trying successful SQL injection why the result isn't getting displayed on the webpage?

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

1. Below is the PHP code I wrote that allows SQL injection with one parameter ie 'id' in this case.
2. On trying SQL injection via putting this    2' ORDER BY 1;--'   in the parameter (id field ), I get only SQL errors on the page.
3. On executing the query directly on mysql server ie SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '2' ORDER BY 1;--'';    I get the below result that is 1 row set along with the error.

> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '2' ORDER BY 1;--'';
> +----+----------+-----------+------------------+
> | id | username | password  | creditcard       |
> +----+----------+-----------+------------------+
> |  2 | John     | password! | 3123456769384659 |
> +----+----------+-----------+------------------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual       that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax     to use near '--''' at line 1

---

PHP code

```
<?php

require_once 'login.php';
if (!isset($_GET['id']))
{
    echo <<<_END
    <pre>            <h1>WELCOME to the KINGDOM</h1>
    <form action = 'si2.php' method = 'GET'>
    id <input type = 'text' name = 'id'>

        <input type = 'submit' value = 'cl1ck M3'></pre></form>
 _END;

}

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $id = stripslashes($_GET['id']);

}
$connection = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if(!$connection) die ("Unable to connect with MySql " . mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db($db_database,$connection) or die('Could not connect with the database');

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
}
else { echo "Could not execute the Query:  <br>" . mysql_error();}


if($rows >= 1)
    {

        for ($j=0 ; $j < $rows; ++$j)
            {
                $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                echo "Hello $row[1]"."<br>";
                echo "Your Credit Card Number is  $row[3]"."<br><br>";
                echo $query."<br>";
                //echo $row[3];

            }
    }           
else
{
    echo "<br><br><br>Sorry no rows/results could be fetched on query execution <br><br><br>";
    //echo $query;
}
?>
```

My question is why my code isn't able to fetch the row set and displaying the table entries ? And in case I want to then what changes should I try.

Comment: Note that [MySQL (theoretically) requires whitespace or control character after the `--`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comments.html).

Comment: @Gumbo Got your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error and Problems in your injection**

The problem is that you cannot execute multiple queries with `mysql_query`, and as you are injecting a `;` you have multiple queries. The first one is `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '2' ORDER BY 1` and the second one is `--''`.

The first one is the one that gives you the actual result in the command line, and the second one gives you your error (because it's not a valid query).

Note also that your injection: `2' ORDER BY 1;--'` doesn't make all that much sense. Why do you have the `;`? You don't really want to execute two queries, just one. And what is the last `'` supposed to do? You already took care of the leftover `'` by commenting it out via `--` (at least in theory).

**Solution**

What you want to inject is `2' ORDER BY 1--`, or, if that doesn't work, try using `#` (url encoded as `%23` if you use a browser) instead of `--` as comment character to cut of the rest of the query (the `'`), because it does not require an additional whitespace. In some cases you could also build the query in a way that the left over `'` is used, such as `OR '1' = '1` (this probably doesn't work for order by though).

Comment: Your clear description has explained where I's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are possibly two issues with your attempt that cause it to fail:

- [Syntax for MySQL comments to the end of the line `--`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comments.html)  requires a whitespace or control character following the double-dash:

  > From a “`--` ” sequence to the end of the line. In MySQL, the “`--` ” (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on). This syntax differs slightly from standard SQL comment syntax, as discussed in [Section 1.8.2.4, “'`--`' as the Start of a Comment”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ansi-diff-comments.html).
- [PHP’s `mysql_query` function](http://php.net/mysql_query) does only allow one single statement:

  > **mysql_query()** sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) […]

Comment: Is that considered multiple queries?

Comment: @AbeMiessler I’m not sure.